# Class vs Struct binding issue in wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding

**Student class**

```
public class Student
{
    string name;        
    List<SubjectInfo> subjectInfoList;    
    ....
}
```

`List<SubjectInfo>` List can have different number of `SubjectInfo` objects for different students.

**SubjectInfo struct**

```
public struct SubjectInfo
{
    string subjectCode;
    int marks;
    ...
}
```

I want to display student object detail on a window. Since **List** have different number of object count I used `ItemsControl` and used dataTemplate.

Binding a student object works perfectly.

```
Student student = new Student("Joe", new List<SubjectInfo>() { new SubjectInfo("Subject1", 50), new SubjectInfo("Subject2", 70) });  
StudentGrid.DataContext = student;
```

But this `TwoWay` binding is not working for `SubjectInfo`(Changing value from UI will not caught by the codebehind)
But if change **SubjectInfo struct** to **SubjectInfo class** it works.

Cannot understand why. Please advice me.

Comment: It could be a copy issue.. leave it as a class.

Comment: Understanding the difference between structures and classes is pretty important. You might want to give this a read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

Comment: @LewsTherin- Thanks everyone for quick responce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By assigning a `SubjectInfo` to `DataContext`, it is copied (because it is a `struct`/`ValueType`), that's why the binding does not work. This is in most cases not what you want. I suggest you use a class for `SubjectInfo` instead.

You should be aware of the differences between `class` and `struct`. The [C# Specification (V4.0)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552) summarizes them like this (in section 11.3):

- Structs are value types (§11.3.1).
- All struct types implicitly inherit from the class `System.ValueType` (§11.3.2).
- Assignment to a variable of a struct type creates a *copy* of the value being assigned (§11.3.3).
- The default value of a struct is the value produced by setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to `null` (§11.3.4).
- Boxing and unboxing operations are used to convert between a struct type and `object` (§11.3.5).
- The meaning of `this` is different for structs (§7.6.7).
- Instance field declarations for a struct are not permitted to
  include variable initializers (§11.3.7).
- A struct is not permitted to declare a parameterless instance constructor (§11.3.8).
- A struct is not permitted to declare a destructor (§11.3.9).

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick response.

Comment: If I place this students object in `ObservableCollection`,does the `Struct` object behaves the same?

Comment: @NewDeveloper Yes, assigning a struct to something else will copy it. Really, i don't see *any* reason to use a struct here. Only use a struct if you really want your objects to be copied **every** time. And this is almost never the case. I suggest you just use a class.

Answer (score 1):

Struct is a value type and binding will obtain a copy of it hence never update original object.

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick response.